# Creating a function to calculate realized gains of stock using FIFO method based on transactional history

Tags: google-apps-script, stock, fifo

I am new to google app script and trying to learn as much as I can but I have stumble against something which is over my head.....

My aim is to create a function, which calculates the realized gains of a stock, given the input data of the transactional history, in the accounting style "FIFO", which stands for first in, first out.

The formula for calculating realized gains is relatively straight forward

```
(Total Sell price - Original Cost ) = Realized gains/loss 
Realized Gains/Loss / Original Cost = Profit/loss (%)
```

If someone has bought a stock at three different times for three different prices (x1,x2,x3) and you wish to calculate the 'realized gains' - do you take the original cost of x1, x2 or x3? FIFO style would take X1, as it is 'first in, first out'. This is important because in the US there is something called capital gain tax based on all realized gains.

Here is my data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V7CpCxBH0lg6wi1TAhfZJP5gXE8hj7ivQ8_ULxLSLgs/edit?usp=sharing

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const historySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Blad1');

function fifoProject () {

  let input = historySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let onlyBuyRows = input.filter(row => row[2] == 'Buy');
  let roundedTotal, priceQuantityMultiplication;
  let onlyColABDF = onlyBuyRows.map(row => {
    roundedTotal = Math.round(row[5] * 100) / 100;
    priceQuantityMultiplication = row[3] * roundedTotal;
    return [
      row[0], row[1], row[3], roundedTotal, priceQuantityMultiplication
  ]});
  let sorted = onlyColABDF.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
    if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
    if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
    return 0;
  });
  let arrayBuyData = [];
  arrayBuyData.push(sorted);
  console.log(arrayBuyData);
  //ss.getSheetByName('output').getRange(1, 1, sorted.length, sorted[0].length).setValues(sorted)

 let input2 = historySheet.getRange(2, 1, historySheet.getLastRow() - 1, 4).getValues();
  let onlySellRows = input2.filter(row => row[2] == 'Sell');
  let sellTotalArray = []
  let addAllSellObject = onlySellRows.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr[1] in acc) {
      acc[curr[1]] += curr[3]
    } else {
      acc[curr[1]] = curr[3]
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

  let addAllSellArray = Object.entries(addAllSellObject).sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
    return 0;
  })
  sellTotalArray.push(addAllSellArray);
  console.log(sellTotalArray[0][1]);
  }
```

Here is what I think the function should do:

https://ibb.co/Pr0gC1S

Any idea's in the right direction would be very welcome.

**EDIT: Trying to clarify the question. Wish to do this:**

```html
<style>
    .demo {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    }
    .demo th {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
        background:#F0F0F0;
    }
    .demo td {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
    }
</style>
<table class="demo">
    <caption></caption> <thead> <tr>        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Amount p.p</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Jan</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Buy</td>
        <td>&nbsp;$10</td>
        <td>&nbsp;5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Feb</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Buy</td>
        <td>&nbsp;$15</td>
        <td>&nbsp;8</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For example if then 7 quantity sold for $23, it would result in:

```html
<style>
    .demo {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    }
    .demo th {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
        background:#F0F0F0;
    }
    .demo td {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
    }
</style>
<table class="demo">
    <caption></caption> <thead> <tr>        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Buy price p.p</th>
        <th>Profit p.p</th>
    </tr>   </thead>    <tbody> <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Jan</td>
        <td>&nbsp;5</td>
        <td>&nbsp;$10</td>
        <td>&nbsp;$13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Feb</td>
        <td>&nbsp;2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;$15</td>
        <td>&nbsp;$8</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

TOTALS:

```html
<style>
    .demo {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    }
    .demo th {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
        background:#F0F0F0;
    }
    .demo td {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
    }
</style>
<table class="demo">
    <caption></caption> <thead> <tr>        <th><br></th>
        <th><br></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Total buy price</td>
        <td>&nbsp;$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Total sell price</td>
        <td>&nbsp;$161</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Total profit (or loss)</td>
        <td>&nbsp;$81</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT 2: Based on the answer of Jacques, I have created the following code:**

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const historySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Blad1');
    
    
// Function which pushes item x amount of times based on a number
    function pushNumber (number, array, item) {
      for(var i = 0; i<number; i++){
        array.push(item);
      }
    }
    
    function shiftNumber (number, array, item) {
      for(var i = 0; i<number; i++){
        array.shift(item);
      }
    }
    
    function projectFIFO () {
    let input = historySheet.getRange(3,1,historySheet.getLastRow()-1, 5).getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i<security.length; i++) {
      let action = row[2].toString();
      let quantity = Number(row[3]);
      let price = Number(row[4]);
      let emptyArray = [];
      // console.log(quantity);
      for (security of array) 
      if (action === 'Buy') {
        let numberPush = quantity;
        pushNumber(quantity, emptyArray, price);
      };
      console.log(emptyArray);
    };
    }
```

Basically I have created a helperfunction pushNumber, which pushes based on the amount of Number. Then in the fifo function I create a for loop to go through each row and see if there is a buy and push the buy based on the amount of quantity, the push is inside an empty array. However, I would like to learn how to do this for every security seperatly instead of the entire range. I think perhaps an object is a solution but haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Could you please break down and simplify you question?

Comment: @idfurw Made edit to question to try to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying your code and the example Sheet I see that you are very close to accomplishing your goal. You only have to code a function that interacts with your *Transactions* table in order to get the data for your desired results table.

In the first interaction, filter the *Transaction* table to only show your desired ticket (as you did in the example script). Proceed to interact the table from the top to the bottom (you can use the [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)/[`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) as shown in your example). Now, for every *Buy* row, [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the price as many times as shares bought. So for example if you bought 3 shares at $313, you should push `313, 313, 313`. For every *Sell* order you only have to [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) the array and calculate the difference between the returned value (buying price) and the selling price.

With that approach you are going to effectively develop a FIFO logic that manages the buying and selling orders, so the difference between them will be the realized profit. Feel free to leave a comment if you have doubts about this approach.

---

## **UPDATE**

You can use this approach to remove duplicates from an array. This would be useful if you don't know the names of the securities beforehand.

```js
var allTickers = ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', '2222.SR', 'MSFT', 'AMZN',
  'AAPL', '2222.SR', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', '2222.SR'
]
var uniqueTickers = [...new Set(allTickers)];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I think your method makes a lot of sense and it is a great answer. However, I have difficulty trying to achieve what you have suggested. I will edit my question to show you the code I have created so far to execute your plan. Perhaps you can add some suggestions.

Comment: I read your update and the new code. If the only change that you need is to manage each security separately, you only need a small change. When the `input` is being created, just after the range is set, you should create a filter with [`createFilter`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createfilter) and [`setColumnFilterCriteria`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setcolumnfiltercriteriacolumnposition,-filtercriteria) in order to focus only on the desired security. Please test this approach and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. For example, what Filter criteria would I use? I can try and use 'whenTextCointains(text)', but normally I wouldn't know beforehand know the names of the securities.

Comment: I was assuming that you already knew the names of the securities, in that case you are right by using that filter. If you don't know the names beforehand, there is a workaround that you can use. First you should take every security in an array, and then you remove the duplicates. Please see my example in the update.